# You broke Bing's search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I performed the following search on Bing:

> stackoverflow input string not in a correct format site:stackoverflow.com

and got some useful links, with some not so useful summaries:

[image: Bad summaries]

I did the same search on Google and that one seems to be working OK, but Bing hasn't had this problem before (and it doesn't seem to affect all questions). Of course; it could be an issue with Bing's code but wanted to put this up in case its something SO changed.

Comment: Flagged comments; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176829/discussion-on-question-by-bradleydotnet-you-broke-bings-search-results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subsequent layout updates resolved this - tidying up meta and marking this as completed :)

Answer (score 77):

As mentioned above, this is likely happening because the cookie banner is one of the very first textual elements in the HTML ordering.

Another solution would be to wrap the cookie banner in an `iframe` and then set the `robots.txt` to block access to the `iframe`.

```html
<body>
  <iframe src="/path/to/cookie/iframe">
  The rest of the content goes here!
</body>
```

and in `robots.txt` you would disallow `/path/to/cookie/iframe`

I strongly disagree that this is Bing's fault BTW – as content owners of the page, it's up to you to help put semantic information first so that everyone (screen readers, crawlers etc) get the best experience.

Comment: Didn't even think of screen readers. Hearing that text over and over again as the first thing on the page would drive me nuts.

Comment: That last paragraph 100%. This is basic webmastering.

Comment: I bet users of screen readers are super-annoyed by GDPR yada-yada.

Comment: @bendodge, aren't we *all* super-annoyed by GDPR yada-yada?!

Comment: The problem of putting the frame last is, that you want to assume that reading it is binding consent (I doubt it, but that's off topic), so you need to put it at a prominent place.

Answer (score 8):

This unfortunately appears to mostly be by design.

The biggest part of it is that "stackoverflow" is one of your search terms and the summary is trying to highlight parts of the page with your search terms.  Omitting either `stackoverflow` or `site:stackoverflow.com` seems to help Bing figure out that you aren't looking for pages about Stack Overflow but pages on Stack Overflow.

This is surprisingly hard to experiment with because of what appears to be aggressive caching on Bing's part.  E.g., if I drop all references to Stack Overflow, I'll still get pages from Stack Overflow with "Stack Overflow" bolded like it was a search term.

We may look at moving some content around and watching if it improves things, but some of it would be difficult.  For example, it's finding content that's in one of the topbar's `display:none` dialogs.  That both is hard to move because of the way that pages are constructed and upsetting to me because it means Bing is ignoring CSS.

Comment: Maybe send them a support inquiry about that last part?  It seems to make them vulnerable to some blackhat SEO techniques.

Comment: There is a "feedback" button somewhere on the page. I'd start with that.